# Uncaught RangeError: byte length of Int16Array should be a multiple of 2

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, browser-extension, lame

I'm trying to fetch some audio files using a custom chrome extension. At the moment I have this code that will start fetching the data when a certain page is opened using `webRequest` API

```
//
let isListening = false;
let stream = [];

const createChunksFromStream = (details) => {
  const chunkUrl = details.url;
  fetch(chunkUrl)
  .then( (res) => res.blob() )
  .then( (res) => {
    console.log(res);
    const fr = new FileReader();
    fr.readAsArrayBuffer(res);
    fr.onloadend = () =>{
      stream.push(new Int16Array(fr.result));
    }
  });

}

const processChunks = (stream) => {
  console.log(stream);
  const mp3encoder = new lamejs.Mp3Encoder(1, 44100, 320);
  for(const chunk in stream){
    const mp3buffer = mp3encoder.encodeBuffer(chunk);
    if(mp3buffer.length > 0){
      stream.push(mp3buffer);
    }
  }
  mp3buffer = mp3encoder.flush();
  stream.push(mp3buffer);
  console.log(stream);
} 

const initStream = (status) => {
  console.log(status);
  if(status !== true){
      chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.removeListener( createChunksFromStream );
  }else{
    chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener( createChunksFromStream,{
      urls: ['https://website.net/audio/*'],
      types: ['xmlhttprequest']
    },['responseHeaders']);
  }
}

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener( (tab) => {  
  if(isListening !== true){
    isListening = true;
    initStream(isListening);
    alert('Ripping');
  }else{
    isListening = false;
    initStream(isListening);
    if(stream.length > 0){
      processChunks(stream);
    }
    alert('ripping stopped');
  }
});
```

I've added this [library](https://github.com/zhuker/lamejs) to the background script section of the estension manifest to be able to call it inside the `background.js` script of the extension. As documented on the library repo, it will accept `Int16Array` to create mp3. The chunks I get from the site for each `fetch` request are all like this:

```
Blob {size: 3209513, type: "application/octet-stream"}
size: 3209513
type: "application/octet-stream"
```

I've tried to convert the blob to Int16Array but I get this error

```
Uncaught RangeError: byte length of Int16Array should be a multiple of 2
    at new Int16Array (<anonymous>)
    at FileReader.fr.onloadend (background.js:16)
fr.onloadend @ background.js:16
FileReader (async)
(anonymous) @ background.js:14
Promise.then (async)
createChunksFromStream @ background.js:11
background.js:37
```

Is there something wrong with the code?How I can fix this?

Comment: Have you tried use `Int8Array` instead?

Comment: @Keith no I didn't